# Print binary tree nodes

Tags: c++, data-structures, recursion, binary-tree

I'm programming a BinaryTree project. I finished all (insert, delete, create, find) but one function, the printing operation. I'm supposed to print it like this:

```
5
46
X557
XXX6XXX9
```

Basically print all the nodes, but print an X if the node is empty. I've been trying to figure out how to do this and I keep hitting a dead end. Would this be something like inorder-traversal?? Thank you

Comment: It sounds like you want a breadth-first search.

Comment: Why would a binary tree have empty nodes?  My understanding is that when nodes (or values, items) are deleted, the tree is restructured to eliminate empty nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Level-Order traversal (Breadth First Search) printing each node as you go through a level, with a newline at the end of each level.

You can find BFS pseudo-code [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search)

Comment: simply doing BFS wont take care of printing a X if the node is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BFS but with a slight modification:

In simple BFS, after visiting a node you add its children to the queue. If no children, 
nothing is added.

For your problem, if there are no children for a node that is visited, add a special node to the queue with its value as "x" so that it will print the "X" in your output correspondingly. Print a newline after each level.

Answer (score 0):

As Dream Lane said, BFS would work here. I offered my own JAVA implementation here for your reference.

```
public static void printBST(Node root) {
    // empty tree
    if (root == null)
        return;

    Queue<Node> que = new LinkedList<Node>();
    que.add(root);
    boolean allChildNull = false;// end condition

    while (que.size() > 0 && !allChildNull) {
        allChildNull = true;
        Queue<Node> childQue = new LinkedList<Node>();

        for (Node n : que) {
            // print out noe value, X for null
            if (n == null)
                System.out.printf("%1$s", "X");
            else
                System.out.printf("%1$s", n.value);

            // add next level child nodes
            if (n == null) {
                childQue.add(null);
                childQue.add(null);
            } else {
                childQue.add(n.left);
                childQue.add(n.right);
                if (n.left != null || n.right != null)
                    allChildNull = false;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("\n");// newline
        que = childQue;
    }
}
```